# How to stub a constructor from an imported ES6 module?

Tags: javascript, testing, constructor, stub, deno

I would like to stub the constructor of a class within a test file. Say I have the following:

```js
// Foo.js
export class Foo {}
```

and

```js
// myTestFile.js
import {Foo} from "./Foo.js";
import {functionThatUsesFoo} from "./functionThatUsesFoo.js";

class ReplacedFoo {}

// do something to replace `Foo` with `ReplacedFoo` here...

functionThatUsesFoo();
```

Is there some magic `Object.setPrototypeOf()` or `Foo.prototype = ReplacedFoo` sort of call that I can do to make sure `functionThatUsesFoo()` uses my stubbed constructor. I'd prefer not to resort to dependency injection.

Most resources I found about this topic were using nodejs `require()` and a testing library that uses node:vm internally. But I'm using Deno/browser environments where this is not easily available.

Some things I tried:

- `Foo.constructor = ReplacedFoo.constructor`
- `Foo.prototype.constructor = ReplacedFoo.prototype.constructor`
- `Foo.prototype = ReplacedFoo.prototype`
- `Foo.prototype = ReplacedFoo`
- `Object.setPrototypeOf(Foo, ReplacedFoo.prototype)`

I made [a library](https://deno.land/x/fake_imports) to solve situations like these that allows you to replace the contents of imported files. But it has some inevitable limitations so I want to avoid it where possible. Similarly, using import maps to solve this isn't really a satisfying solution either as it doesn't scale well and I might as well use the library at that point.

Comment: No, this is not possible. You will need dependency injection or mess with the module system (before importing the `./functionThatUsesFoo.js` module)

Comment: @Bergi ah that's too bad :/ Thanks though!

Comment: Import maps are the correct solution. You will probably need to introduce a new abstraction to your test running strategy.

Answer (score 1):

with .mjs you basically want to re-work your code to dependency injections everywhere. and functions to double fat arrows :P

```
const makeFunctionThatUsesFoo = (fooInstance) => (funcAgs) => {
 console.log('I feel secure, but stubs stoped working')
}
```